# Debug DNS: What to do if host name resolution does not work as expected?

Tags: domain-name-system, debugging

The current search results for "debug dns" don't reveal a guide-line what to do, if you (as user/client) think there is something wrong with the host name resolution.

What steps can I do to narrow down the problem?

My particular case:

The tool `host` can resolve the name:

```
root@mypc# host remotehost.internal-domain.local
remotehost.internal-domain.local has address 10.99.204.11
```

But the tool `nslookup` can't:

```
root@mypc# nslookup host remotehost.internal-domain.local
nslookup: couldn't get address for 'remotehost.internal-domain.local': not found
```

I am confused.

## Solution

In my case I changed this line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

to this

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Now the .local Domain gets resolved by DNS, not by avahi peer-to-peer stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What steps can I do to narrow down the problem?

In general: Many commands come with switches that increase the verbosity and/or the debug level allowing you to troubleshoot more easily.  Check the manual page for the exact options, i.e. [`man host`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host) and [`man nslookup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup)

In the case of DNS issues:

- a fairly typical problem is the presence of static entries in `/etc/hosts`
- your system may use alternative hosts database configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and when you use tools that only test actual DNS name servers you get different results compared to what your system resolves.
- your /etc/resolv.conf may contain multiple nameservers and one or more of those responds differently from the other(s), check by querying each specific name server directly